# random number selection

Tags: matlab, random

I have an arrey of random numbres and zeros. How can I randomly select a positive number from them and with some probability, say 20% replace it with another value otherwise keep it the same?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo Code

```
While Selected Number Is Not A Positive Number
      Select Random Index Between 0 and Size of Array - 1
      If Number at Index is Not Positive then continue to next iteration
      Else
      Generate Random Number Between 0 and 1
      If Random Number is less than 0.2 //20%
          Set Array[selected index] = some other value
```